# How to find step size of NDSolve for using in FEM

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am using `Method -> MethodofLines` as an `NDSolve` method. My boss wants me to implement my code to a FEM solver. (I have a very little knowledge of FEM) For that I need to know what step size in time and space is used by NDSolve with MethodofLines. I checked [the Method of Lines tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) and several posts here, but couldn't find anything.

For spatial discretization the tutorial notes that the default value is given as Automatic. Is there a way learn what corresponds to Automatic? And do you know what is the time step for this method?

Thanks!

Comment: We can use  Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]. See tutorial on the page  Utility Packages for Numerical Differential Equation Solving.

Comment: @AlexTrounev thanks! You mean ```Map[Length, InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[ifun]]``` i guess, isn't it? My t=(0,2500) and x= (-200,200) but ```Map[...] ``` gives ```{16156, 25}```. Does it mean it computes with $\Delta$x=16? That seems too big as a spatial step size.

Comment: It depends on option what you use. If there are no options, then `NDSolve` automatically run 25 points for PDE and sends some message about this.